# better monadic for fails to desugar tuples

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I am trying to incorporate [better monadic for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) into a project for it's lovely tuple desugaring which doesn't appear to be working currently. I have:

- added the plugin in my `plugins.sbt`: `addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1")`.
- I have downgraded my scala version from `2.13.2` to `2.13.1`
- and I've updated my code as follows to take advantage of the desugaring as follows

I have a helper method with the following signature:

`def helper(shifts: List[Shift], taskMap: Map[String, Double]): F[(Int, Int)]`

It is being called as follows:
`(offProd, prod) <- helper(shifts, taskMap)`

without the desugaring it compiles fine.

I'm using sbt version `1.5.8` and I have recompiled and reloaded the project in metals to ensure the compiler plugin is included. The only thing I can think of at this point is maybe the plugin is not being picked up automatically in my build.sbt, as I haven't updated it to use the `plugins.sbt` as I'm assuming sbt does that for you.

Comment: **bm4** is a compiler plugin, not a **sbt** plugin. You must add it to your `build.sbt` instead of `project/plugins.sbt` - PS: You don't need to downgrade your **Scala** version at all, rather ruse the latest one `2.13.10`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I wasn't importing the plugin into my project via `plugins.sbt`. As [luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez) (i.e. the G.O.A.T.) pointed out in the comments, `better-monadic-for` is a compiler plugin not an sbt plugin and must be added to your `build.sbt`.

I adding the plugin to my library dependencies in my `build.sbt` instead worked:

`compilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1")`

(e.g.)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.14.1",
  //... more typelevel libraries here
  compilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1"),
)
```